# How to debug a Java swing application that freezes Windows?

Tags: java, windows, swing, freeze

I am in the process of development of a stand-alone (Swing) Java EE client. The application server is JBoss 6.1.0. Some Windows workstations freeze while the client is running, some do not. Both 32-bit and 64-bit Windows workstations freeze, and again, some 32-bit and 64-bit Windows workstations work perfectly. The client runs well on Linux without any problems.

I have followed instructions from StackOverflow where people suggested to disable direct draw with `-Dsun.java2d.noddraw=true`. It did not help.

What puzzles me the most is that some workstations are almost identical - the same Windows version, the same graphics drivers, the same JRE, yet some work well, some do not.

The application uses the Preferences API a lot to store various positions of dockables (from the Docking Frames project), it uses JBoss client classes.

I am in the process of investigating if perhaps concurrent access to the Windows registry is causing this problem (if you had similar problems please let me know)...

First guess was that a race condition occurs somewhere in the GUI thread, and the GUI freezes. But that would freeze only the GUI, it should not freeze the whole Windows.

The machine, once frozen, responds to pings, however no Windows service works.

I would appreciate *any* hint that can help me solve the problem.

**Edit:**

- CPU usage is always around 10%.
- Number of threads never goes above 30, however not all threads are daemon threads (this includes AWT threads, RMI threads, etc).

Comment: does your CPU usage go to 100%?  It sounds like you have a different problem, but I wanted to rule this out.

Comment: I checked that as well - at the time it freezes CPU usage is actually quite low - typically ~10%.

Comment: Have you tried comparing in deeper detail workstations that work with the ones that freeze? Perhaps its a service pack level, some optional patch/driver getting in your way...

Comment: Yep, I did - some drivers did not have the same versions. Having the same drivers is really difficult...

Answer (score 1):

Try out the [EventQueue with Watchdog](http://www.roseindia.net/javatutorials/edt_lockup_detection.shtml). You install an alternative EventQueue in the Application. The Watchdog tells you which Events are locking up your GUI.

Comment: I will definitely try this! Thanks keuleJ!

Answer (score 0):

It turned out to be ESET. On every Windows machine that had ESET installed I had this problem. Apparently ESET has this "protocol tracking" feature that is ON by default. Once turned off we never had this problem.